# Proof about Matrix representation in Linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, linear-transformations

If dimV = m , dimU = n , F : V -> U : linear
dim(ImF)=r then there exists bases of V and U s.t matrix representation of F has the form 
$$
\pmatrix{I_r & 0\\0 & 0}
$$
(where Ir is r-square identity matrix)

step(i) :

I found that  basis of kerF has m-r elts that is, {W1,W2,...,W(m-r)} 
and dimension of V is m.

step(ii) :

So I want to set basis of V as {V1,V2,...,V(r),W1,W2,...,W(m-r)}

for this process, I learned some theorem about this, but I can't remember it. I want to know what theorem need from step(i) to step(ii)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many linear algebra texts, you should be able to find a statement of the form

> Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$.  If $S = \{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ is a linearly independent set in $V$, then $S$ can be *extended to a basis* of $V$.  That is, there exist vectors $v_{k + 1}, \dots, v_n$ such that $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$.

I don't think this theorem is usually given a name.  However, it is often presented as a corollary to the [dimension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces).  I am confident that the dimension theorem is proven in Friedberg Insel and Spence, and I suspect that this corollary is presented shortly thereafter.

Comment: I have heard somewhere Extension theorem. :)

Comment: @srijan I could believe it, but usually "extension theorem" refers to a result about being able to extend the domain of a function from a subset to the entire space.

Comment: Ya I am agree with your opnion. More specifically extending the basis of a subspace to a basis of a vector space.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you so much. And I got one more problem while proving this, I want to prove that each value of V1 s.t F(V1),...F(Vr) is basis of Im(F), and I think maybe I should the theorem that any spanning set with r elements is basis of Im(F), am I right?

Comment: That's not necessary here.  Of course, $\{F(v_1),\dots,F(v_r), F(w_1),\dots,F(w_{m-r})\}$ is a spanning set for $Im(F)$.  Since $F(v_1) = \cdots = F(v_r) = 0$, it suffices to show that $F(w_r), \dots, F(w_{m-r})$ are linearly independent.  To show that these vectors are linearly independent, note that if they were **not** linearly independent, then we could necessarily find another element of $\ker(F)$ from the span of $w_r,\dots,w_{m-r}$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks, but I mean  F(v1)=⋯=F(vr) spans Im(F) and I want to show each of them are linearly independent. I can't get that F(v1)=⋯=F(vr) = 0 since v are vectors in V not in kerF.

Comment: Sorry, I switched the $v$'s and $w$'s.  I mean that it suffices to show that $F(v_1),\dots,F(v_r)$ are linearly independent.